# How to prevent ListView.builder widget from rerendering when item is clicked

Tags: flutter, listview, widget, bloc, statefulwidget

I am using a ListView builder widget inside a stateful widget class to display a categories menu. Inside this categories menu I created a method which is passed as parameter to CategoryItem class to handle the click event. Inside the CategoryItem class, when it is selected, a border is added to it. The problem is that every time I'm clicking a new item, the entire CategoryMenu is re-rendered. How can I avoid that?
Here is how it looks like:
[image]
**My CategoryItem class:**

```
class CategoryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Category category;
  final bool isSelected;
  final Function() onTapCategoryItem;

  const CategoryItem({
    super.key,
    required this.category,
    required this.isSelected,
    required this.onTapCategoryItem,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = AppTheme.of(context);
    final borderColor =
        isSelected ? theme.colorTheme.black : theme.colorTheme.transparent;

    return Wrap(
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: onTapCategoryItem,
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 10,
              bottom: 4,
              left: 5,
              right: 5,
            ),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                width: 3,
                color: borderColor,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              color: theme.colorTheme.white,
            ),
            child: Wrap(
              children: [
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Image.network(
                      category.categoryThumb,
                      height: 50,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 14),
                    Text(
                      category.categoryName,
                      style: theme.textTheme.h2,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**and the CategoriesMenu class:**

```
class _CategoriesMenuState extends State<CategoriesMenu> {
  late final CategoriesBlocBloc categoriesBloc;
  late final MealsBloc mealsBloc;
  late final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onTapItem(int index, Category category) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
    sharedPrefs.setString(
        Constants.selectedCategoryNameKey, category.categoryName);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    categoriesBloc = getIt<CategoriesBlocBloc>();
    mealsBloc = getIt<MealsBloc>();
    sharedPrefs = getIt<SharedPreferences>();
    categoriesBloc.add(const CategoriesBlocEvent.getAllCategories());
    sharedPrefs.setString(Constants.selectedCategoryNameKey, "Beef");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = AppTheme.of(context);

    return BlocBuilder<CategoriesBlocBloc, CategoriesBlocState>(
      bloc: categoriesBloc..add(const CategoriesBlocEvent.getAllCategories()),
      builder: (context, state) {
        return state.map(
          initial: ((value) {
            return Container();
          }),
          loading: ((value) {
            return const LoadingWidget();
          }),
          emptyList: ((value) {
            return Center(
                child: Text(
              LocaleKeys.categories_no_categories_available.tr(),
              style: theme.textTheme.h2,
            ));
          }),
          failure: ((value) {
            return Center(
                child: Text(
              LocaleKeys.errors_something_went_wrong_message.tr(),
              style: theme.textTheme.h2,
            ));
          }),
          completed: ((value) {
            return _categoriesMenuSection(
              value.categoriesList,
              theme,
              widget,
            );
          }),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _categoriesMenuSection(
    List<Category> categoriesList,
    AppTheme theme,
    Widget widget,
  ) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 120,
      child: ListView.builder(
        addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          return CategoryItem(
            onTapCategoryItem: () {
              _onTapItem(index, categoriesList[index]);
              mealsBloc.add(
                MealsEvent.getMealsByCategoryName(
                    categoriesList[index].categoryName),
              );
            },
            category: categoriesList[index],
            isSelected: index == _selectedIndex,
          );
        },
        itemCount: categoriesList.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using BLoC library to handle the state inside the CategoriesMenu class.
This is my BLoC handler class:

```
@LazySingleton()
class CategoriesBlocBloc
    extends Bloc<CategoriesBlocEvent, CategoriesBlocState> {
  final ICategoriesRepository _categoriesRepository;

  CategoriesBlocBloc(
    this._categoriesRepository,
  ) : super(
          const _Initial(),
        ) {
    on<CategoriesBlocEvent>((event, emit) async {
      await event.map(getAllCategories: (event) async {
        emit(const CategoriesBlocState.loading());
        final categoriesList = await _categoriesRepository.getAllCategories();

        categoriesList.fold((categoriesResponse) {
          if (categoriesResponse.isNotEmpty) {
            emit(CategoriesBlocState.completed(categoriesResponse));
          } else {
            emit(const CategoriesBlocState.emptyList());
          }
        }, (failure) {
          emit(CategoriesBlocState.failure(failure));
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: try this, In CategoriesMenu class: remove bloc from BlocBuilder( builder:....).

Comment: if I remove the `bloc: categoriesBloc..add(const CategoriesBlocEvent.getAllCategories())` line, I'm getting a ProviderNotFoundException

Comment: did u use BlocProvier before for this page ?

Comment: I don't know exactly what do you mean @JBJason

Comment: did u use BlockProvider anywhere in project ...?

Comment: Yes, I have a Bloc class, should I update my question and add the code for that class too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252150/discussion-between-razvan22-and-jb-jason).